# Error with installation of HDF-EOS5 augmentation tool: Cannot find -lGtcp

Tags: gcc

I am trying to compile the HDF-EOS5 augmentation tool. However, when I run:

```
./configure --with-hdfeos5=/HDF-EOS5-path/
```

I get the error:

```
checking for inv_init in -lGctp... no
configure: error: invalid Gctp in hdfeos5
```

When I try to check the config.log files, I get:

```
configure:3571: $? = 0
configure:3580: result: yes
configure:3608: checking for compress2 in -lz
configure:3633: gcc -o conftest -g -O2   conftest.c -lz  -lm  >&5
configure:3633: $? = 0
configure:3642: result: yes
configure:4325: checking for inv_init in -lGctp
configure:4350: gcc -o conftest -g -O2  -
I/home/midawn/ClimateResearch/hdfeos5//include  -L/home/midawn/ClimateResearch/hdfeos5//lib conftest.c -lGctp  -lz -lm  >&5
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lGctp 
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
configure:4350: $? = 1
configure: failed program was:
| /* confdefs.h */
| #define PACKAGE_NAME "aug_eos5"
| #define PACKAGE_TARNAME "aug_eos5"
| #define PACKAGE_VERSION "2.2"
| #define PACKAGE_STRING "aug_eos5 2.2"
| #define PACKAGE_BUGREPORT "help@hdfgroup.org"
| #define PACKAGE_URL ""
| #define PACKAGE "aug_eos5"
| #define VERSION "2.2"
| #define HAVE_LIBM 1
| #define HAVE_LIBZ 1
| /* end confdefs.h.  */
| 
| /* Override any GCC internal prototype to avoid an error.
|    Use char because int might match the return type of a GCC
|    builtin and then its argument prototype would still apply.  */
| #ifdef __cplusplus
| extern "C"
| #endif
| char inv_init ();
| int
| main ()
| {
| return inv_init ();
|   ;
|   return 0;
| }      
configure:4359: result: no
configure:4369: error: invalid Gctp in hdfeos5
```

Comment: By any chance did you manage to solve this error? I am experiencing it as well...